# CStr does not handle 3 decimals figures with comma

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following issue.

When I try to do :

```
cell.value=CStr(cell.value)
```

it works with numbers like 6,91.
But when I try with numbers like 6,911 I get 6911 in return when I just want 6,911 instead.
I'm using commas because I'm in Europe, I guess maybe VBA mixes it up with the American way of writing thousands with a comma.

Indeed, here I only want a decimal with 3 figures after the comma

Comment: Cell is a terrible name for a variable in Excel VBA. Can you please post more coide so we can see how you are declaring cell.

Comment: If  you want to format a cell, use its `NumberFormat` property

Comment: @freeflow I disagree - cell is a very good name. Pretty clear what you are referring to after all. :)

Comment: @freeflow Doesn't sound like I'd want to work for you. What's your issue with cell? It's not used by vba or the excel OM.

Comment: ... longstanding confusion about how `Cells` is part of the Excel Object Model but `cell` is *definitely* not.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I would argue that Cell is a poor choice of variable name when other better names exist.  The use of Cell as a name is too close to what **could** be an Excel object.  In addition '.Cell' **is ** a Word object.   I have naming strategies which help in this situation and my way to resolve this conundrum is to prefix any variable defined within a method with 'my'.  It is my opinion that 'myCell' is a much much better name for a variable then just 'Cell'.  I have other similar naming strategies which greatly improve the readability of code.  If you pm me I am happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not what you expect it to do

```
cell.value=CStr(cell.value)
```

Here  `CStr(cell.value)` will turn it into a `String` but if you write a string into a cell that looks like a number Excel *"thinks"* and turns it back into a number. Here comes the confusion.

If you want to format that cell as text use

```
Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
Cell.Value = Format$(cell.Value, "0.000")
```

or use `Cell.Value = "'" & Format$(cell.Value, "0.000")`